# Make changes in unsrt bibliography style

Tags: bibtex

I have a question on changing the order of first/last names of authors using in  unsrt bibliography style. I tried with other styles but the closest to what I need is unsrt with a little change.

**Unsrt gives the reference as given below**

M. Velasquez and P. T. Hester. An analysis of multi-criteria decision making methods. International Journal of Operations Research, 10(2):56–66, 2013.

**But I would like something like this**

Velasquez, M and  Hester, P.T., An analysis of multi-criteria decision making methods. International Journal of Operations Research, 10(2):56–66, 2013.

I just need to change the appearance of first name and surname in this bibliography style. Could you please help on this matter?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is most easily done with `biblatex` and the option `[sorting=none]`: if it isn't already enabled by default, you have toadd to your preamble: `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}`.

Comment: Thanks @bernard  but I couldn't understand how can I add '\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}' to unsrt bibliography style?

Comment: To do that, you have to change  `\bibstyle{unsrt}+bibtex` to `\usepackage[sorting=none, backends=bibtex]'biblatex}` and add `DeclareNameAlias{…}` afterwards in your preamble (this is a biblatex command). Alo preferably, replace `bibtex` with `biber`.

Comment: my codes are: \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{8}
\usepackage[sorting=none, backends=bibtex]{biblatex}        
Is there a problem using natbib?

Comment: In this case, it is not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: It can't work with two packages for bibliography.  If you want to use`biblatex`, don't use `natbib`, and vice-versa. Note you can have an emulation of natbib in biblatex  (option `natbib`). Comment aside: don't load `graphics` if you load `graphicx` (the latter does it for you), and loading packages once is enough; you might have problems if you load them with different options.

Comment: In using biblatex, there was an error and it couldn't find the reference. In using natbib, it work but there is no changes about the order of the name and surname.  Is there a problem adding \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} to the begining of the document?

Comment: Only biblatex will understand that. Could you provide a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{8}
\usepackage[sorting=none, backends=bibtex]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\begin{document}
... \citep{Benayoun1966}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refer}
\end{document}

Comment: My reference folder 
@book{Benayoun1966,
  title={Manual de Reference du Program {ELECTRE},Note de Synthese et Formation},
  author={Benayoun, R. and Roy, B. and Sussman, N.},
  series={Princeton University. Econometric Research Program. Research memorandum},
number={25},
  year={1966},
 publisher={Direction Scientifique SEMA},
 place={{P}aris, {F}rance}
}

Comment: @Bernard, Sorry, I had to split them. Please kindly find my codes. and my reference file

Comment: I've just posted  a suggestion with `biblatex+biber`. I hope this is about what you want. I took the liberty to add accents to letters which required them in the bibliography.

Answer (score 3):

I also struggled with `unsrt` and the sorting of the first and last names in the bibliography.

I use `Texmaker 4.3, MiKTeX 2.9`, and there is an easy fix for it:

- Copy the `unsrt.bst` file from the MiKTeX directory from the folder "MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\base" into the folder of your `.tex` document and rename it (e.g. `unsrt2.bst`)
- Open it with the editor and go to the section `FUNCTION {format.names}`
- Rewrite the following line `{ s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=` to `{ s nameptr "{ll}{~ff}{~vv}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=`
- in the `.tex` file use the new style: `\bibliographystyle{unsrt2}`
- enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what can be done with `biblatex+biber` (one important feature of biber, as compared with `bibtex` is it understands `utf8`; hence you may typeset accented letters directly in the `.bib` file).

I took the liberty to change the font package from `times`, which is obsolete to the much more recent and complete `newtxtext`, `newtxmath`, which is based on `TeX Gyre Termes`, a Times clone.

Note the syntax with biblatex is different from traditional bibliography packages: you have to declare the `.bib` data bases(s) in the preamble, in the form:

```
\addbibresource{mydatabase.bib}
```

then write `\printbibliography` in the document, where you want it to be.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refer.bib}
@book{Benayoun1966,
 title={Manuel de Référence du Programme {ELECTRE}},
 subtitle = {Note de Synthèse et Formation},
 author={Benayoun, R. and Roy, B. and Sussman, N.},
 series={Princeton University Econometric Research Program. Research memorandum},
 number={25},
 year={1966},
 publisher={Direction Scientifique SEMA},
 location={Paris, France}
 }
    @book{cap,
    title ={Le Captain Cap. Ses aventures, ses idées, ses breuvages},
author = {Alphonse Allais},
   publisher = {Juven},
year = {1902},
location = {Paris}
    }
}
%
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx, setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
%\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress, round]{natbib}
\usepackage{multirow}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\onehalfspacing
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{8}
 \usepackage[sorting=none, firstinits, style=numeric-comp, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{no. #1}

\addbibresource{refer.bib}

\begin{document}

... \parencite{Benayoun1966}

Yumyumyum…
\cite{cap}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]